# List all pdf files in Android Devices

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to list all PDF files which are stored in internal and external memory of Android device using ListView. However,I have no idea now, and the only way I can think of is checking file extension. So would you please give me a hint or suggestion? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question is from 2011, the topic is still relevant and there's no proper answer here.

So this code below should work on today's Android devices:

```
String selection = "_data LIKE '%.pdf'"
try (Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), null, selection, null, "_id DESC")) {
    if (cursor== null || cursor.getCount() <= 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // this means error, or simply no results found
        return;
    }
    do {
        // your logic goes here
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: how to get the file name and location inside do while then?

Comment: @m__ you can debug the code, and see in runtime which columns (and their values) you get with that cursor. Specifically, look out for those listed [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.FileColumns) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns).

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for: [MediaStore.Files](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.html)

> Media provider table containing an
>   index of all files in the media
>   storage, including non-media files.
>   This should be used by applications
>   that work with non-media file types
>   (text, HTML, **PDF**, etc) as well as
>   applications that need to work with
>   multiple media file types in a single
>   query.

Comment: `MediaStore.Files` is only for API 11+

Comment: Hmm now im curious how previous pdf applications usually handled that

Comment: hi all, after spending two days on trying, I have to say that MediaStore.Files can not work in Android. So, if anyone have other suggestions, please share. Thanks.

Comment: PDF file isn't media. I tried it and I couldn't succeed.